# Calculating price from <span> value and <input> value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Today I try to calculating the price from `<span>` value and `<input>` value. And then, put the result in `<span>`.

I already tried this code. This is my html:

```
<td class="cart-product-price">
    <span id="price" class="amount">19.99</span>
</td>    
<td class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity clearfix">
         <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
         <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="2" class="qty" />
         <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
    </div>
</td>    
<td class="cart-product-subtotal">
    <span id="total" class="amount"></span>
</td>
```

So I want to get price value from `<span id="price>`, get quantity from `<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">`, and put the result in `<span id="total" class="amount"></span>`

This is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val()) || 0;
    var qty = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
    var total = price*qty;
    $('#total').text(total);
</script>
```

**Note: I am using JQuery for increase / decrease quantity (plus & minus button)**

Did I wrote something wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is my increase / decrease javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // This button will increment the value
            $('.plus').click(function(e){
                // Stop acting like a button
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get the field name
                fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
                // Get its current value
                var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
                // If is not undefined
                if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    // Increment
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
                } else {
                    // Otherwise put a 0 there
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
                }
            });
            // This button will decrement the value till 0
            $(".minus").click(function(e) {
                // Stop acting like a button
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get the field name
                fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
                // Get its current value
                var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
                // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
                if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    // Decrement one
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
                } else {
                    // Otherwise put a 0 there
                    $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?  Did you see what the values of price and qty are in your JS function?  What result do you get in #total?

Answer (score 1):

The 'price' field is a `span`, which do not have a `value` property. Instead, you need to read the `text()` from it. Also note that the 'quantity' field has an `id`, so you would be better to use that as a selector as it's much faster. Try this:

```
var price = parseFloat($('#price').text()) || 0;
var qty = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
var total = price * qty;
$('#total').text(total);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bnm07vt7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = parseFloat($('#price').text()) || 0; //parseFloat($('#price').val()) || 0;
var qty = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
var total = price * qty;
$('#total').text(total);
```

The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input , select and textarea

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2zkbvhoL/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>

            .active {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var price = parseFloat($('#price').text()) || 0;
            var qty = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
            var total = price * qty;
            $('#total').text(total);
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td class="cart-product-price">
    <span id="price" class="amount">19.99</span>
</td>    
<td class="cart-product-quantity">
    <div class="quantity clearfix">
         <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" field="quantity">
         <input type="text" id="Text1" name="quantity" value="2" class="qty" />
         <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" field="quantity">
    </div>
</td>    
<td class="cart-product-subtotal">
    <span id="total" class="amount"></span>
</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>

    </html>
```